Как сделать внутренний отступ placeboard текста в input
Есть такой код:


.but-d {
  padding: 0 px 800 px;
  text - indent: 0 px;
}

.but-ds {
  width: 1000 px;
  height: 100 px;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  border - radius: 5 px;
  /* Уголки */
  font - size: 30 px;
}
<div class="but-d">
  <input class="but-ds" type="search" placeholder="Поиск по сайту" />
</div>



Как сделать отступ placeholder="Поиск по сайту" чуть подальше от края самой кнопки

В класс but-ds добавьте padding-left: 15px;
